# Erro para abrir aplicação

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Boa tarde,

Eu clonei um repositorio que usa angularJS e node.js.
Gostaria de rodar ele, porém ao clicar em

> "index.html"

o site aparece incompleto.

No terminal, dentro do repositório eu coloquei isto para ver se rodava

> diretório$ nodemon app.js

Sendo app.js um arquivo do repositorio clonado
Porém continua não rodando, aparece o erro:

```
[nodemon] 1.11.0
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
/home/junior/Documentos/GitLab/skipq-web/src/js/app.js:3
  var App = angular.module("App", [
            ^

ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at /home/junior/Documentos/GitLab/skipq-web/src/js/app.js:3:13
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/junior/Documentos/GitLab/skipq-web/src/js/app.js:241:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:427:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:148:9)
```

Alguém sabe o que devo fazer para rodar?

O meu `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "meuprojeto",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.8",
    "del": "^2.2.2",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-inject": "^4.2.0",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^2.0.1",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.13.1",
    "run-sequence": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp-main-bower-files": "^1.6.1",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/.../....git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/.../.../issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/.../...#readme"
}
```

Comment: testa correr `diretório$ webpack` para compilar os ficheiros. Podes mostrar o `package.json`?

Comment: Quando eu corro o `diretório$ weback` isso acontece: `webpack
webpack: comando não encontrado`

Comment: Podes colocar o `package.json` desse projeto aqui, ou num link? Pode ser que precises compilar ficheiros com o webpack ou browserify. Se o webpack não está instalado tens de fazer `npm install webpack -g`. Presumo que já correste `npm install` para instalar o projeto.

Comment: Você inseriu a tag `<script>` com a referência para a biblioteca do *angular.js* dentro do teu **HTML**??? Além disso, ele precisa ser carregado antes de carregar o **app.js**.

Comment: Como eu carrego o **app.js**? Sim, fiz referencia para a biblioteca _angular.js_ no **HTML**

Comment: Conseguiu resolver essa questão? Para notificar uma pessoa quando responder pra ela, escreva o nome dela assim: `@nomedapessoa olá...` (importante, se não a pessoa esquece que está falando com você aqui!)